# Nested for loop with numbers and "-"

Tags: java

This is the problem:

Write a method called printDesign that produces the following output. Use nested for loops to capture the structure of the figure.

```
-----1-----
----333----
---55555---
--7777777--
-999999999-
```

This is what I have:

```
public static void printDesign() {

    for(int dashAmt= 5; dashAmt >= 1; dashAmt--){
        for(int dash = 1; dashAmt <= dash; dash++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int numAmt = 1; numAmt <= 9; numAmt+=2) {
            for(int num = 1; num1 <= numAmt; num++) {
                System.out.print(num);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how would I get the dash in the same line as the number so I can get this:

```
-----1-----
----333----
---55555---
--7777777--
-999999999-
```

Comment: Why not try yourself?? I guess it is a homework problem.

Comment: you've used the `println()` and `print()` methods so I assume you know the difference. The answer is just within playing with those methods :) your close, don't give up if this is a homework :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 2 `System.out.println();` from each `for` loop and put in the outer `for` loop.

```
for(int dashAmt= 5; dashAmt >= 1; dashAmt--){
        for(int dash = 1; dashAmt <= dash; dash++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
//        System.out.println(); // Removed
        for(int numAmt = 1; numAmt <= 9; numAmt+=2) {
        for(int num = 1; num <= numAmt; num++) { // Its num and not num1 - typo by you
                System.out.print(num);
            }
//            System.out.println(); // Removed
        }
      System.out.println(); // Put it here.
    }
```

**Note:** This only solves your `sysout` problem. Your logic is wrong nevertheless, and I'm not fixing that. Do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PrintDesign {
        public static void main (String args[]) {
           printDesign();
        }

          public static void printDesign() {
           int b = 0;
           for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i += 2) {
                for (int k = 0 ; k < 5 - b; k++) {
                  System.out.print("-");
                }
                    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(i);
               }
                    for (int k = 0 ; k < 5 - b; k++) {
                        System.out.print("-");
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("");
                    System.out.println("");
                    b ++;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: add explanation to your answer